# can i use aws cognito for kibana from cloudformation when creating elastic search domain?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-elasticsearch

I am writing a cloud-formation script to create an elastic search domain
but from the docs, I couldn't find a way to include cognito to use with kibana . How can I include it?

I have tried below script to create .(Parameters & roles ignored here)

```
  ElasticsearchDomain: 
    Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Sub "${ElasticsearchDomainName}" #getting Name From Parameter
      ElasticsearchVersion: "6.5"                   #specify version
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig: 
        InstanceCount: 1
        InstanceType: "m4.large.elasticsearch"     #instance type
      EBSOptions: 
        EBSEnabled: true
        Iops: 0
        VolumeSize: 10
        VolumeType: "gp2"
      SnapshotOptions: 
        AutomatedSnapshotStartHour: 0
      AccessPolicies:                        # who can acess & their permissions
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              # AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root"  #root account
              AWS: "*"  #All account
            Action: "es:*"
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:es:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:domain/${ElasticsearchDomainName}/*"
      AdvancedOptions:
        rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index: 'true'
```

So, as shown above, where should I include cognito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way currently to add Kibana Cognito Authentication through Cloud Formation. You will have to do so manually through the console.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is possible to add Kibana Cognito Authentication via CloudFormation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticsearch-domain-cognitooptions.html